# How to code the view holder binding when using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data,MyViewHolder>adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, MyViewHolder> ("what to put here?") {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Data model) {

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

I was trying to do a recycler view where in I can put the FirebaseRealtimeDatabase

Comment: Did you see the documentation on [using FirebaseUI to populate a RecyclerView](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview)? It contains step by step instructions on how to use the adapter.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions <Data> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder <Data>().setQuery(query, Data.class).build();
```

`Data` : Is your class.

`query` : Is your DatabaseReference that reference, your data node that you want to populate in the recycler view.

And pass this `options` to the place that you are referring to:

```
//here
.... = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, MyViewHolder> (options) {
```